# Invalidating pages using android paging library

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I am using the pagin library in alpha5. 
My problem is, that my list I want to load using the android paging library, is very often changed. Like multiple times per minute. When I scroll down and load page 1,2,3 (atm I am using a PositionalDataSource for that) it could happen that page one is invalid while scrolling further down.

Try to imagine that page 1 got invalid for some reason and the user is on page 5 (not on the same screen as page 1 is) now he's scrolling up to page 1 again. the paging library is taking the data from cache so there's old data, which is bad.

Is there a way of invalidating pages?
I would expect that when I scroll up, that there's an (optional) call (possibly in the DataSource itself) which asks if the data from the cache is stil valid.

If that's the case, everything is fine, if not, use the methods to reload your source (db, network, whatever)

Comment: if your `DataSource` changes the only way to notify the outside world is to call `DataSource#invalidate()` method

Comment: I dont want to reload the whole list, but the "old" pages.

Comment: you cannot do that, see `DataSource` javadocs, section: `Updating Paged Data`

Comment: Hello @andre were you successful in using PositionalDataSource? As in my example it is getting stopped after initial load ...

Comment: Except the missing feature, it was working as expected, yes

Answer (score 1):

As noted by pskink if your `DataSource` changes the only way to notify the outside world is to call `DataSource#invalidate()` method. If the reason you don't want to reload unchanged pages is because you use some slow data source (for example on the network), you should cache the data using Room. You will be able to update only the parts of the cache that have changed, you won't need to write your own DataSource, and the one provided by Room will invalidate itself when the cache has been changed so the display can be updated.